# How to search within a string to extract data from OSM other_tags?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, query

I am working with OSM data in QGIS and I often need to query items in the other tags field. When I download the data using the OSM  download plugin the other tags come in one field so are not easy to use.

Currently I am looking at permissive paths etc

"foot"=>"permissive","horse"=>"permissive","tracktype"=>"grade2"

I can use the expression (badly written) below to pull out what I want and perform a selection but it is a headache. any better ideas? I have tried quick OSM but that doesn't seem to have access to the details in the other tags

substr(  substr(  "other_tags" , strpos( "other_tags",'foot"=>') ,70),10,strpos( substr(  substr(  "other_tags" , strpos( "other_tags",'foot"=>') ,70),10,20),'","')) = 'permissive'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd suggest an alternative approach: Download raw OSM data and use OGR to prepare your data in such a way that the relevant tags are not mashed together in the "other_tags" column. This can be achieved by customizing OGR's osmconf.ini file as documented in http://www.gdal.org/drv_osm.html.

Look for the lines

```
# keys to report as OGR fields
attributes=name,highway,waterway,aerialway,barrier,man_made
```

and add your keys such as foot, horse, and tracktype.

Then you can, for example, create a Spatialite database using ogr2ogr

```
>ogr2ogr -f "SQLite" -dsco SPATIALITE=YES -spat 2.59 46.58 -1.44 47.07 noirmoutier.db noirmoutier.pbf
```

as described in http://anitagraser.com/2014/05/31/a-guide-to-googlemaps-like-maps-with-osm-in-qgis/

Comment: After this pointing me in the right direction I used import to xml and export to spatialLite (from OSM menu in qgis) where I could select all the wonderful tags I fancied.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, you saved me a ton of work.

Answer (score 4):

Since **QGIS 3.6**, you can use **Explode HStore field** algorithm in Processing Toolbox. This algorithm will explode your HStore field into many fields.

There is also support for HStore expression in QGIS since **QGIS 3.4** :

- `hstore_to_map`
- `map_to_hstore`

Before QGIS 3.6, you can also use the QuickOSM plugin in QGIS.
You can open a local OSM file and get all keys as a column. QuickOSM will split the "other_tags" column as you want.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to extract all relevant ways from Overpass API using regular expressions. Here's an example which returns only ways with a `permissive` value in any key in the current bbox.

```
[bbox:{{bbox}}];
way[~"."~"^permissive$"];
(._;>;);
out meta;
```

Overpass Turbo Link: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/9ML  (Hit "Run" to test)

You can use pretty much the same syntax from within QuickOSM as well.

Comment: That looks handy but the syntax is a bit beyond me

Comment: It's really not that difficult:

Line 1: Restrict ways to current bounding box.
Line 2: Just select ways, which have "permissive" in any of its keys. This would match e.g. foot=permissive, or horse=permissive.
Line 3: Return ways along with their nodes (to get all lat/lon details as well).
Line 4: Return all data including meta data (version, timestamp, etc.).

I hope this clarifies the syntax a bit. Give it a try in QuickOSM.